# Asp.net - Refactor action

Tags: c#, .net, asp.net, refactoring, dry

I have this "problem" that i have code like this in many of my controller actions:

```
var users = new List<SelectListItem>();
foreach(var user in userRepository.GetAll())
{
 var item = new SelectListItem { Text = user.FriendlyName, Value = user.UserId.ToString() };

 if (User.Identity.Name == user.UserName)
  item.Selected = true;

 users.Add(item);
}

ViewData["Users"] = users;
```

How would you refactor this to a more clean solution? I want to get DRY!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would create this to be an extension method applied to `List<user>` or whatever your userRepository.GetAll() returns so then in your code you can replace all of these usages with just

```
ViewData["Users"] = userRepository.GetAll().ToSelectList();
```

**Edit code sample:** There's 2 ways you could do this

```
public static List<SelectListItem> ToSelectList(this List<Agent> users)
{
    List<SelectListItem> items = new List<int>();
    foreach (var user in users)
    {
        var item = new SelectListItem { Text = user.FriendlyName, 
                                Value = user.UserId.ToString() };

        if (User.Identity.Name == user.UserName)
            item.Selected = true;

        items.Add(item);
    }

    return items;
}
```

And usage would be like

```
userRepository.GetAll().ToSelectList();
```

Or if you have problems with identity being in the extension method have

```
public static List<SelectListItem> ToSelectList(this List<Agent> users, 
                                                        string selectedUserName)
{
    List<SelectListItem> items = new List<int>();
    foreach (var user in users)
    {
        var item = new SelectListItem { Text = user.FriendlyName, 
                                Value = user.UserId.ToString() };

        if (user.UserName == selectedUserName)
            item.Selected = true;

        items.Add(item);
    }

    return items;
}
```

And usage would be like

```
userRepository.GetAll().ToSelectList(User.Identity.Name);
```

Comment: Yes, i have this approach on other similar situation. The problem? is that i need to set the current user as the selected item. What would be the best way to solve this?

Comment: User.Identity.Name is static already so you can use that inside your extension method just the same.

Comment: I would probably add some null checking to that code since Identity might not exist at all times, say during unit tests, and if it gets called in a test case it'd be better off skipping the Selected = true block than throwing an exception.

Comment: Would that logic go in the ToSelectList then?

Comment: IMO this is clearly helper class code, any "helper class" is almost always a code smell unless it can be turned into an extension method and be globally available for a specific type which this fits in for and I think would make the most sense since really all you're doing is ToADifferentTypeOfList()

Comment: Thanks for the example. One thing i don't like is that i have to reference System.Web.Mvc from my datalayer to access SelectListItem, do I have to live with that?

Comment: I think that might be the cost of using the SelectListItem class, i've encountered this also frequently using System.Web.UI.ListItem for similar purposes as you have. The tradeoff of referencing a web assembly is a fair price to pay instead of having to rewrite a List control for the selected item functionality to be supported by a custom object. You could atleast try replicated the SelectItem class with a custom class with a Selected property and bind it to your control and see if it picks up the selected value based off reflection looking for a .Selected property instead of hardcoded types

Comment: It might also have a DatasSelectedField like dropdown lists have DataTextField / DataValueField when you databind. I haven't done anything with MVC in a long time so I'm not sure off the top of my head how the control stuff works anymore.

Answer (score 1):

Put that code, or part of the code into a separate class - let's call it UserService. Let UserService implement IUserService:

```
public interface IUserService
{
    IEnumerable<SelectListItem> GetUsers();
}
```

Inject IUserService into your controller via Constructor Injection:

```
public MyController(IUserService userService)
{
    this.userService = userService;
}
```

Use the `userService` field in your Controller Actions to get the users.

```
public ViewResult DoSomething()
{
    var users = this.userService.GetUsers();
    // the rest of the implementation
}
```

Comment: While I agree this is good design, I'm not really sure it needs a whole service created for it when it's really just a type conversion operation.

Comment: I like this solution too. I already have a IUserService so this would fit nicely.

Answer (score 0):

You could place that logic in an (abstract) BaseController and then derive all your controllers from it and have them call a method in the BaseController to get that data as needed.

If you need to include it in *ALL* your controller actions you could also place it in an overridden OnActionExecuting() in the BaseController.